# Can you see what's wrong with this apache2 rewrite rule?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2.2

Want to redirect `/dl/[dlcode]/[cleanname].mp4` to `/dl/cache/[dlcode].mp4`

Got AllowOverride All in the apache2 config file then the following in the document root .htaccess,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^dl/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.mp4$ /dl/cache/$1.mp4 [NC]
```

I've been trying it with files that def exist. Both the [dlcode] and [cleanname] just contain a-zA-Z0-9 characters

Cheers for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases you need to add a leading slash:

```
RewriteRule ^/dl/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.mp4$ /dl/cache/$1.mp4 [NC]
```

Comment: Cheers for the help, turns out I needed to specify the RewriteBase.

Comment: That would be my second guess. However I'm happy that you found a solution.